# K6 Load Test write to csv file

Tags: javascript, k6

Hi I am trying to get the ID_Context from an httpp response and save it in a csv file. But when I try the below using papaparse I get error

*ERRO[0042] GoError: the "open" function is only available in the init stage (i.e. the global scope), see https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/test-life-cycle for more information
running at go.k6.io/k6/js.(*Runner).newVU.func2 (native)

default at openFileAndWrite (file:///C:/Users/*******)*

```
// Extract ID_Context from the response and store it in the variable
    const idContext = response.body.match(/<Reference Type="16" ID_Context="([^"]+)"/)[1];

    // Append the ID_Context to the data array
    data.push({ ID_Context: idContext });
}

export function handleSummary(data) {
    // Convert data array to CSV using Papa Parse and write to a file
    const csv = papaparse.unparse(data);
    console.log(csv); // Print CSV to console (optional)
    openFileAndWrite('output.csv', csv);
}

// Helper function to write content to a file
function openFileAndWrite(fileName, content) {
    const file = open(fileName, 'w');
    file.write(content);
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: remove one of the duplicates please

Comment: You cannot call `open` from the test, setup, teardown, or summary functions, you need to open the file in the init context, i.e. outside of any of the functions.

Comment: @JaromandaX, I don't know why there is a duplicate, but I deleted the other one.